# Can I make a function in R return a named object?

Tags: r, function, return-type

I want to write a function that creates a time series, but I'd like it to generate the name of the time series as part of the call.

Sort of

```
makeTS(my.data.frame, string(dateName), string(varName)){
-create time series tsAux from my.data.frame, dateName and varName
-create string tsName
(-the creation of tsAux is not a problem)
assign(tsName, tsAux)
return(tsName)
}
```

This, perhaps not surprisingly, returns the string `tsName`, but is there any way that I can make it return a named object?

I've tried with

```
do.call('<-', list(tsName, tsAux))
```

and I've also tried using

```
as.name(tsName) <- tsAux
```

but nothing seems to work.

I know that

```
tsName <- makeTS2(my.data.frame, dateName, varName)
```

would do the trick (where `makeTS2()` just generates the time series `tsAux` and returns it), but is there any way to make it work with one function call?

Thanks!

Comment: You can assign to the global environment from within a function with `<<-`. Also, `?assign`.

Comment: it's almost certainly better to return a named `list` instead. `makeTS <- function(dat, varName) {
  list(varName = dat)
}`

Answer (score 8):

**Can** you? Sure:

```
makeTS <- function(dat, varName) {
  result <- NA
  assign( varName, result, envir = .GlobalEnv )
  result
}

> makeTS(NA, "test")
[1] NA
> test
[1] NA
```

**Should** you?  Almost surely not.

Comment: There is no "almost" there. If someone gave me code with such a side-effect, I'd be not amused.

Comment: I was giving him/her the benefit of the doubt--maybe they just wanted to learn about environments?  Unlikely I know, but y'know.  Hey @user3060988: if you want to know more, read http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html and http://digitheadslabnotebook.blogspot.com/2011/06/environments-in-r.html and `?environment`.

Comment: Just curious: Is there any particular reason why I shouldn't do that? I'm going to do a lot of additional analysis with the time series, and I'm going to do the same analyses with different time series, so I don't see why creating it in one step instead of two is a problem - mind, there's a naming convention that should guarantee consistency and uniqueness of names.

Comment: @SiKiHe Perhaps the shortest truly honest answer is that declaring a "rule" that this is a bad idea will lead you towards far better ways of solving your actual problem.  What problem are you trying to solve--there's like a better way.  Taking a wild guess, you may want to create a list to hold all your model results, then each model is a named element of the list.  That sets you up to do `lapply`, `foreach`, or any number of other R-like operations on the list, instead of having a bunch of models littering your global environment.

Comment: Well, a data frame actually, rows being the names of the models and columns various constants such as RMSE, MPA etc. The task is finding good models for a time series in order to do PA. I'll be looking at one time series at a time, though.

Comment: For that I would use a list as described above, maybe adding a column with the model name repeated over and over.  If the data.frames all have the same number and types of columns, you could then use something like `taRifx::stack.list()` to stack them all into one big data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Ari B.' answer is good. You could also use `assign()` with a variable.

```
> makeTS <- function(dat) {
+   return(666)
+ }
> varName <- "tmp"
> tmp
Error: object 'tmp' not found
> assign(varName, makeTS(1))
> tmp
[1] 666
```

Comment: I agree `LauriK`.  From the other examples of acceptable solutions, the OP may be satisified with this, even though it's more in the spirit of `tsName <- makeTS2()` which they rejected.